# Integer conversion to floating point type by python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a newer in python study,when I run the following program:

```
 self.QRSpeaks -= 40 * (self.samplingrate / 1000)
```

The problom I encounted is :

```
self.QRSpeaks -= 40 *(self.samplingrate / 1000)       
    TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc subtract output from dtype('float64') to  dtype('int32') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you for your reply

Comment: what is `self.QRSpeaks` innitial value?

Comment: I am sorry for later reply for network delay. It is a int type. Here ,I want change 40 *(self.samplingrate / 1000)   into float 64,how can I slove it ?

Comment: show `self.QRSpeaks` and `self.samplingrate` initail values

Comment: I am sorry that the program is copied from someone else,and I just begin to learn the program. The program can't go down,so I can get the value.What I can sure is that self.samplingrate is samplingrate,It must be int type.

Answer (score 0):

Casting mean this self.QRSpeaks -= 40 * (self.samplingrate / float(1000))
Or self.QRSpeaks -= 40 * (self.samplingrate / (1000*1.0))

and the main problem discuss here : 
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7225

you can use: casting='unsafe'

example: np.add(a, b, out=a, casting="unsafe")

Comment: I tried just now.It doesn't work,and the problem I encounted is the same as the former.So I want change 40 *(self.samplingrate / 1000)   into float 64,how can I do it?thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I have sloved the problem based on your reply.